# How can I recreate the graininess seen in the blue/red backgrounds?

Tags: photoshop-effects

How can I recreate the graininess seen in the blue/red backgrounds in Photoshop?
Also does anyone know what font is used for the word "Cyrus"?
[image]

Comment: Looks like a light grunge texture has been used. There are approximately one billion of these available for free download with a google search, give that a try.

Comment: Google for a tutorial "simulate film grain in Photoshop". You don't need to buy or download anything.

Answer (score 0):

If doing this purely in photoshop you could find a grunge texture in 'Pattern Overlay' the effects palette in photoshop.

For the blue you can combine it with a radial gradient overlay to get the aesthetic you are looking for.

I agree with @tobybot, in that you will probably get a better look by finding a grunge texture pack online, there are loads of great free ones.

Smashing Magazine has great selection of tutorials for example:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/40-beautiful-grunge-photoshop-tutorials/

[image: Selecting the Overlay]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple texture overlay, but a complex one. See, how the grain appears as 3D especially on the highlights of the red part. Lets get it.

Have your image as a layer (=Image). Insert another layer over it (=Grey+Grain). For that layer:

- set blending mode = Hard light
- fill with 50% grey
- insert a grainy texture, for example Filter > Artistic > Film Grain. Other comments and answers suggest other textures.
- reduce the opacity to make the effect less dominat

Here is a snapshot of what we have now; The opacity of the Grey+grain is not reduced.

[image]

Here the opacity is reducet and the effect is weaker. This may be enough for some parts of the image. For those parts save a copy of the layer. Use a layer mask or eraser to target the grain effect.

[image]

Next we increase the complexity. Start with adding a slight - say 0,5 ... 1 pix - Gaussian blur to Grey+Grain layer - just smoothen a little the edges of the flakes.

Emboss the grain for the appearance of depth. It can be a layer style or filter. Lets go Filter > Stylize > Emboss:

[image]

NOTE: It's well possible that a satisfactory 3D-ish texture is available without any filtering.

Add some highlights and shadows. Add a layer again with blending mode = hard light between the image and Grey+Grain. Paint with large, smooth brush white and black. Have a low brush opacity - only a few percent. In addition you can reduce the layer opacity. An example:

[image]

The painted area has left and right edges to show the effect clearly. NOTE: The added Highlight & Shadow layer makes nothing special other than darker and lighter areas in the image.